# Add custom product attributes to catalog_product_entity_decimal table?

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute, backend-model

Is there any reason why it impossible to add custom attributes to `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table?

I tried to look up products by weight, length, height, width and started with weigth. Thats a system attribute and is stored in `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table while custom attributes are stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` ...

When adding attributes from backend the only type is `price` that maps to decimal table, but it also set price backend model.

Any reason why there is no option to add a `decimal` attribute?

---

**Update:**

Of course I can change backend type on DB or add the attribute via script, but I'm interessted why its not possible to do it from admin backend.

Answer (score 1):

Magento already has an option to add a decimal attribute. Each attribute's data type is recoded in a column called **backend_type** as bellow:

[image]

So you can add a decimal attribute by add this option:

```
'backend_type'    => 'decimal',
```

After that, attribute value will be saved in **_decimal** table

Regards